# Python combining positive and negative matches on the same line

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to search through an apache log file in order to pull out lines that do not have certain strings ("session" and "curl") and the lines must have a particular month string ("Dec").
The searches work on their own:

```
re.search("^((?!session|curl).)*$", f[line])
re.search(r'Dec', f[line])
```

I am wondering if I can get away with combining them in a single join?
I tried this

```
re.search('|'.join('(?:{0})'.format(x) for x in (r'Dec', r'/^((?!session|curl).)*/$')), f[line])
```

I am expecting to see lines with the correct month, and to have lines with the strings "session" and "curl" excluded, but instead all the lines are returned.

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong without your code and data, preferably in the form of a [MCVE]. Although you might find this simpler with just using grep -v

Comment: some log example will be helpful

Comment: Uh...its apache logs. I'm matching strings in the log lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to construct a regex like

```
^(?!.*(?:session|curl)).*Dec
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hcTQ6R/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(?:session|curl))` - no `session` or `curl` should appear on the line (if you add a DOTALL modifier, the whole string will be considered)
- `.*Dec` - any 0+ chars (other than line break chars if the DOTALL modifier is not used), as many as possible, up to the last occurrence of a `Dec` substring.

Add word boundaries (`\b`) around the group/word if whole word match is required.

Sample [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DVmzAf):

```
import re
words = ['session', 'curl']
month = 'Dec'
x = '|'.join([re.escape(w) for w in words])
m = re.search(r'^(?!.*({})).*{}'.format(x, month), 'Date: Dec 2016')
if m:
    print('Matched')
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked, I put my data in the demo and it came out great!

Comment: Just FYI: `^((?!session|curl).)*$` is a very resource consuming construct (a [tempered greedy token](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970)). Avoid it if possible, use simple lookaheads if you need to match some string other than some other string.